# Ethical Jobs in Careers

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs, ethics

I've noticed an advertisement in Stack Overflow Careers for a company that makes installers that steal the user's browser home page and installs unwanted toolbars and adware without informing the user.

I was wondering if it's Stack Overflow's place to impose any ethical guidelines on which companies are advertised in Careers. Either by the staff or by the community. How does the community and the staff feel about that? Should limits be imposed? When?

Comment: They probably pay a lot of money to Stack Exchange!

Comment: Yes they should. But no, if SO decides no one want to work at Oracle, that would be gross overreach

Comment: As long as the advertised jobs are not blatantly off-topic, I think they *should* be allowed. There is a line between morally despicable practices and plain illegal activities (although this is an ever shifting line, and I am pro persecuting adware companies, for blatantly wasting my time, disk space, and bandwidth). (...That said, I also think Microsoft is evil -- for those same three reasons as well!)

Comment: I think that effecting a persons computer in an unauthorised manner (as most of these software installers do) and then not making the appropiate uninstaller (which I would be surprised if they did, I have never encountered one of these companies who did) is actually classed as computer misuse in some countries, not sure about the US

Comment: @Jhawins good to remember that Javas Ask Jeeves installer clearly states its options, allowing you to unselect them and provides a clear installer. There is no harm in that. As for utorrent: I do not actually download that software anymore. It's "adware" is clealy malware and it disguises the options to not install the software within little installer screens changig the wording of the buttons each time to catch you out. Once a time utorrent was good but now it is just a platform for attempting to dish out malware without totally breaking the law by being an out right virus.

Comment: @Jhawins What do you mean, nobody is boycotting Java?  I don't advise people to install Java on their computers any more thanks to that kind of behavior on their part.

Comment: @Yakk good for you. Java is in so many places the "just boycott it" mentality isn't an option for a ridiculous amount of people even outside of developers. Let's not be silly and pretend everyone can do that. I see your point I really do but it's not real for me, I cannot simply boycott Java. Even so that isn't the point so let's not go off on this "Can we boycott Java" tangent.

Comment: @JHawkin did you notice the damn McAffee crapware download snuck in with Adobe Flash update? Adobe lost 100% of my respect that day. All fantastic products made by Adobe, no longer care. The moment a viable second option becomes available, I will boycott Adobe. The only reason that we don't boycott these companies is because they have no viable competitors.

Comment: @Sammaye you can't be serious. The business model behind the option being selected in the first place is that a large percentage of people in a hurry will not notice the packaged crapware, forget to un-check the option and the company gets paid for the mistake that they ***planned*** for you to make. Its a blatant form of deceit.

Comment: @Tanner no harm. You're a participating community member - having one more person who answers/asks question is worth a lot more than having one more person who sees ads. I just think you shouldn't suggest removing the ADs in public :)

Comment: You can flag the job ad and they will surely remove it.

Comment: @Sammaye "_Every non-technical relative I've ever talked to has toolbars they apparently can't see, apps running in the background, browser home pages set to Russian Google clones, and they have no idea how it got that way. Here's how it got that way._" - [Download Wrappers and Unwanted Software are Pure Evil](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DownloadWrappersAndUnwantedSoftwareArePureEvil.aspx).

Comment: could be one of many GOOD questions that are marked by moderators as not specific or resulting in debate.

Answer (score 197):

> I was wondering if it's Stack Overflow's place to impose any ethical guidelines on which companies are advertised in Careers

Probably not. Perhaps we should get to vote instead, like we do on questions and answers.

Defining what is ethical or not is far from being clear cut. It is an inherently subjective matter.

Who gets to decide where the line is between an *annoying* toolbar, and an *unethical* one?

Is a company that writes code for American military drones unethical? What about Chinese or Russian ones? What about a company that builds software for saving puppies, but which is a subsidiary of, say, Monsanto? Some people would call working for *Facebook* unethical. Would you? And so on.

Ethics guidelines will always be hard to pin down. Instead, maybe we should get to **vote** on job adverts we're shown (like on questions and answers).

That would  allow the community to voice a (subjective) standpoint on job ads.

If an ad receives a thousand downvotes (or whatever) SE could make it a policy to pull the ad and say to the advertiser, "sorry, our community doesn't like your ad."

If it happens thrice in a row, tell them "sorry, but our community doesn't like *you*."

That would also be in keeping with Careers.SO's promise - to show the programmer community *the kinds of jobs they want.*

Comment: "Who gets to decide where the line is between annoying toolbar, and an unethical one?" - well that's what I'm asking. The options as I see it are either "no one" (no screening), "the SE team" (in a hopefully transparent process), "the community" (as in, posting suspicious ads on meta or a similar process) or something different (like someone who specializes in business ethics).

Comment: After the edit and suggestion it's much clearer - I'm keeping the comment for new answers to see though. Thanks.

Comment: Dang it Pekka, your edit scooped my answer

Comment: Perhaps when a company's add reaches a certain negative score they should just start having to pay twice as much... Two birds with one stone. Make more money for Stack Exchange while leaving a warning sign for job seekers.

Comment: Good answer. I really like the idea that I might never see a Philip Morris or Superfish ad just because the community had nuked it - or that an ad for a position with a respected company might rise to the top. I don't think anyone would wind up being treated unfairly - for every Samsung/Apple/Microsoft/Google hater there is a lover. For a company to gain or lose noticeably from such a system there would have to be a real prevailing community sentiment.

Comment: Voting is also highly problematic. Half of the community upvotes the puppy saving company and the other half downvotes Monsanto. A decision made based on limited knowledge. Superfish got lots of upvotes because until recently it was a cool new content providing startup. Now it takes long to outvote the old upvotes. While voting gives you the moral high ground it is also bad at finding the truth and making responsible decisions.

Comment: @nwp I agree, but Careers.SO's aim is arguably to present ads *that the community wants to see*. What better way to do that than to ask them? But voting should definitely be  the limit of it. There's no better way to turn off paying customers that allowing users to comment underneath their ads - I know from painful experience involving a Facebook ad besieged by militant vegans :)

Comment: @AdamEberbach I abhor some of the business practices of a large American retailer whose career adverts I've seen - but others don't (and for what its worth, the technology engineering part of the company looks *really fun*.) I am also working in the public sector of a state now that has a name "Department of ..." and I am sure there are people with issue with the executive decisions made by elected officials deciding its course - but that doesn't mean that it should be hidden or down voted.

Comment: ... this doesn't even begin to touch on some of the tensions between activists. I could easily imagine people down voting job postings for companies that provide outsourced labor (or any job that allows a 'work remote')... or the "could you find a job in country A that is in a state of conflict with country B of which both have active and opinionated tech sectors?" - Being able to filter for what interests *me* may be a good thing... being forced through a filter of what everyone else thinks for a job posting may significantly hurt the bottom line for careers.se.

Comment: Doesn't this disagree with this answer?
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161345/does-stackoverflow-investigate-employers-before-allowing-them-to-post-to-careers

Comment: I don't like this. Boycotts are nasty things, but done right, they can be justified - like many forms of nastiness - because they pressure the boycotted entity into changing its behaviour. An uncoordinated boycott, though, instituted by silent voters without an expressed cause, is going to be almost useless as a way of incentivising a behaviour change. You're proposing keeping everything that is petty and harmful about boycotts while throwing out their potential to do any substantial good. Let these things be centrally co-ordinated, with a clearly voiced goal, or don't do them at all.

Comment: I wonder whether crowdsourced opinions about companies might be better delegated to a dedicated site like Glassdoor. The right tool for the right job.

Comment: Alternatively, this might be a good use of SE's tagging system. Just like you have [javascript] and [ruby] tags, you could have tags for [creates spyware], [shocks kittens], etc. That way programmers could filter jobs by behavior that bothers them.

Comment: Echoing what others said above me, the community shouldn't have such a conclusive say in the matter. Instead of voting, flagging for moderation/staff attention would be much better, as a company's moral standing cannot be explained in `(upvotes - downvotes)`.

Comment: @nwp, This signifies that the voting system needs a do-over, not that voting itself is bad.

Comment: @MarkAmery Out of interest, what are the negatives about a boycott?

Answer (score 91):

> I was wondering if it's Stack Overflow's place to impose any ethical guidelines on which companies are advertised in Careers.

***Yes***, *it most definitely is*.

*(And since this seems to need pointing out: Stack Overflow was founded based on the idea to* ***make the Internet a better place.*** *It should not endorse any business that works against this goal. And if you run a company that hijacks my granny's browser, you do exactly that.)*

Comment: Is that your personal opinion ("yes, IMHO SO should") or are you actually confirming it already is part and parcel of SO's in-take procedure to screen advertisers?

Comment: @Jongware: My profile shouldn't show any affiliation with SE: I like to believe that I rarely publish other people's opinions as my own.

Comment: Stack Exchange [in the past](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161345/159034) has removed (and refunded) career listings for ethical/moral reasons (just search around), so I believe this answer is "yes, they have in the past".

Comment: @Kevin: The question is, "I wonder if it's Stack Overflow's place..." The answer is "Yes." Now you have three guesses what the answer refers to...

Answer (score 42):

> ***Disclaimer:*** These are my own thoughts on the matter. They do not in any way represent the views of Stack Exchange, or Stack Overflow Careers. I'm just a programmer with an opinion.

Discriminating against fields of endeavor opens up a very interesting little box. I'm going to go off on a tangent, but just a *small* one.

Software released under the terms of the GNU GPL (any version) can be used to teach children about kittens or guide nuclear missiles - in fact the license clearly states:

***for any purpose***.

That is to say, there's plenty of precedent in the programming community to produce things and then get the hell out of the way of anyone using them, provided that they do two things:

1. Respect your intent, which is to make the lives of your fellow programmer easier
2. Respect the terms in which people can use whatever you produce in order to meet rule number one

Stack Overflow Careers *doesn't* take anyone with money to spend. In fact, they're more than well-aware of a company wide money back guarantee which is pretty easily stated:

> If you don't like what you got here, you don't have to pay for it.

This means, it's not inconceivable for them to realize that a client simply *isn't* going to be a good fit for *any* programmer using Careers, and politely refund the money they spent after wishing them the best of luck. Because, you know, when you make USB gadgets that shock kittens and you ask your developers to wear those collars during unit tests they must run *during an interview*, you've crossed a line - possibly three.

***But, what if they're hiring folks to work on something else?***

And that's just it - you don't know. I was recruited *twice* (outside of Careers) by folks promising everything that would make Joel just *giddy* to work there, if he worked on file systems and actually needed a job. Both jobs entailed doing really interesting things with something called GlusterFS.

How was I supposed to know that one company operated *hundreds* of thousands of GRE tunnels to Romania helping people send spam, while the other worked on high performance ad servers that knew (and broadcast, for a fee) more about you than most of your friends? *Nothing* about the public presence of either company gave any indicator that these sorts of shenanigans were going on.

***You don't know what good or evil you might be doing until you're given good or evil to do.***

I really hope that we don't get in the business of denying service to companies that (through the way they treat their programmers) are doing exactly what we want companies to do - treat programmers *well*, in a manner that makes them happy to be programmers.

If they can't manage to actually *hire and retain* anyone, then, well, they need to work on their granny-jacking problem and wonder why ping-pong tables and an X-box just wasn't enough.

You *do* actually interview them as they interview you, right? Because - even 'charities' sometimes have ulterior motives.

Comment: How do you (personally) feel about the specific case above of a company whose business model is to make installer software that installs adware and hijacks the home page? You can see the description here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286675/ethical-jobs-in-careers/286745#comment158427_286678

Comment: Also - had it been possible to know in advance that one company is sending massive amounts of spam while the other is a erm... more ethical business - would you like the recruitment service that got you there to let you know? Your answer is a good write up but I can't really distill the answer from it - do you think it's Stack Overflow's place to impose any ethical guidelines on which companies are advertised in Careers. Either by the staff or by the community. How does the community and the staff feel about that? Should limits be imposed? When?

Comment: I think it's the job of SO Careers to make sure employers that advertise make programmers glad that they learned how to program, while taking care to screen "Kitten Shockers, Inc". What's more important is that I expect really smart people to know what they're getting into before getting into it, and to run like hell when those expectations turn out to be unfounded. It's up to you to call shenanigans when shenanigans need to be called, and [quitted that job to find a better one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568471/pass-nothing-from-javascript-to-vbscript-in-ie9) if need be.

Comment: I understand the complexity of you answering this question as an individual and I appreciate your opinion here but that still doesn't really address the actual question very much. It's very easy to say that "SE should not advertise a job at ISIS" - saying that SE should not enable "evil" in obvious cases isn't really answering the harder question I asked two comments above.

Comment: You just compared ISIS to people that install a toolbar on your computer? That's not rhetorical, I'm just trying to keep this grounded.

Comment: Your example was people who shock kittens and make interviewees get electrocuted during the interview. How is that grounded? ISIS was an obvious example of evil like the kitten shock example (maybe not as politically correct) - these examples are _obvious_ and not generally the question I'm asking which is: do you think it's Stack Overflow's place to impose any ethical guidelines on which companies are advertised in Careers. Either by the staff or by the community. How does the community and the staff feel about that? Should limits be imposed? When?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I feel that limits should be imposed when there's an impostor. Careers is _all_ about connecting programmers with jobs that don't suck,  by how the company states that they treat programmers. If folks that interview or go on to work there report unnecessary angst, then yeah, it's time to take a look at them because they're breaking what we promise folks that use Careers. My point is, you can't always tell that from one of the things that they actually make.

Comment: I didn't mean to dodge your first question, I just didn't sufficiently read it.

Comment: So to be clear: Your answer is "Yes, SE should interfere in some cases - if the job posting isn't being honest. However - SE can't always _guarantee_ the jobs themselves will not be fishy because it's out of SE's control.". Thanks, that totally clarifies things :) It would be great if you could edit that into your answer.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Not .. exactly. The question you asked wanted me to arrive at an end of something, but ,, I'm not yet _quite_ ready to call an ending to that trail of thought. You paraphrased it well, but I'm not _quite_ yet ready to make an edit to that effect. I did mark my response as mine only for precisely that kind of reason - I do have thoughts, and assertively as I stated them, they have not yet _quite_ concluded.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum and Tim, you two comment-discuss more efficiently/effectively than some business people communicate across a table, in person. Benjamin +1 for going after your point, Tim +1 for explaining your thoughts so astutely. Interesting 3 minute read..

Comment: _I'm just a programmer with an opinion._ The most dangerous thing in the world.

Comment: Maybe you should have waited for your thoughts to come to some conclusion? Or at least to some milestone on the way to some conclusion. Because after reading your comments I have no idea anymore what you're arguing for or against.

Comment: @sbi I think as stated it's pretty clear, and more than sufficiently expresses how I feel about it. While answering and commenting, I got, well .. how to say it .. _bit_ I guess by a bit of a philosophical bug. It doesn't change the sentiment I expressed, I just feel like I have more to say about it, but no clear way of articulating it. My thoughts definitely conclude here, you should interview _them_ every bit as much as they interview _you_. It was baked enough to post, if that's what you're wondering. Still, I think there's a broader discussion to be had.

Comment: @sbi Ties in with folks having questions that some deem of dubious nature. That sort of thing, just .. a bigger discussion.

Comment: That you should look and think well before you let someone hire you, and that you interview them as much as they interview you is something I said (on PSE?) years ago. However, that doesn't change the fact that there are socially (as opposed to politically) indisputably bad companies out there. I can set why purple cannot agree whether a porn company is bad. However, who would argue that the company which wrote Superfish is a good company? Everything that can be done to hinder such companies should be done.

Comment: And I think SO's original goal of making the web a better place is a pretty good criterion for making such decisions.

Comment: @sbi programmer with opinion? EE with a system patch? manager with an idea? computer scientist with a soldering iron? ... you take your pick for most dangerous.

Comment: @MichaelT: I believe I already have.

Comment: Very well said.

Answer (score 23):

Why stop at guidelines for some vaguely conceived notion of "ethics"?  After all, perhaps Stack Exchange should also censor companies that:

- Promote natural gas as a way to reduce green house gas emissions (better than coal, but worse than everything else).
- Do business in Saudi Arabia, because they discriminate against women and prosecute gays.
- Pay programmers less than the prevailing wage.
- Use the database MS Access . . . because I don't like it.
- In the United States, do not provide health benefits to their employees.
- Avoiding companies who give lots of money to Republicans (in the US).  (Or should that be Democrats?)

If you cannot tell, this answer so far has been sarcasm.  Stack Exchange is quite clear on the guidelines for posting jobs.  They are [here](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/house-rules).

Stack Exchange offers a place where employers can find highly competent technical resources, and a place where those same people can find jobs.  Censoring the job postings for reasons other than legality, actuality (does the job really exist), offensiveness, and coherence seems counter productive.

For example, Stack Exchange does have standards against obviously discriminatory statements, such as "We want a woman between 25 and 35".  Although such statements are legal in many countries (although not the United States), such a statement is offensive to many people and contrary to the notion of getting the best person for a particular job.  I don't believe any of the standards regard legality of business.  So, an online gambling company is allowed to advertise in the US, even though that activity is illegal in (I think) 48 states.

One person's opinion on what is reasonable is likely to be directly contradicted by another person's.  In general, Stack Exchange celebrates that diversity of opinion by giving users various mechanisms to comment on posts, up vote, and down vote.  I do not think that Stack Exchange should be censoring postings, beyond their existing reasonable standards for presentation to a large number of people.

Comment: Thanks, while I generally agree with this I'd love it if you could clarify who, if any, _should_ "censor" or promote or demote those posts. "Stack Exchange celebrates that diversity of opinion by giving users various mechanisms to comment on posts, up vote, and down vote." - it's unclear if you believe that the company should let users take action regarding such posts or not.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum . . . I'm actually ambivalent about that, because it seems like a business decision.  The real purpose of my answer was to point out that Stack Exchange does have guidelines and they are readily available.  As far as I can tell, none of them concern the ethics, legality, or business practices of the companies involved, except for the non-discriminatory piece -- and that is the answer to your question.  Perhaps you should ask another question that is explicitly something like "A proposal to allow users to vote on job lists and/or companies".

Comment: Oh, in that case I apologize for not writing my question in a clear way. I'm aware of these guidelines (and respect SE for them). I'm not asking what they already do. My question is whether or not they _should_ impose ethical guidelines of companies that are advertised in careers and whether or not the community should be involved. This is why this question is tagged with discussion and not with support. There are good arguments for both ways ("Make the internet a better place" vs "The community is the driving force" vs "Who are we to judge?" and also - where does it start and stop?).

Comment: I would support a feature to comment/review companies (I don't think voting would be useful here), similar to Glassdoor.

Comment: Down with MS Access!

Comment: I understand that it is equally tempting and hard to weed out other cruft as well, according to whatever you or I or anyone else thinks is cruft. But I think SO's original goal of ___making the web a better place___ is a pretty good criterion for making such decisions. Add to this Career's goal to ___get programmers into good jobs___, and you have a pretty good criterion (better than that for closing questions because it's _"unclear what you're asking"_) for deciding. Oh yeah, and that's a `-1` from me.

Comment: Incidentally, except for use of MS Access and donations to particular political parties, I agree with your list and think that's a good idea.

Answer (score 11):

I'd say it's totally fine as long as the job posting is not misleading, i.e. it says you'll be working on adware or for an adware-producing company. People can then avoid it if they don't like it, or not if they do.

Comment: As the benchmark - what do you think about: """We created XXX to help developers focus on developing. XXX offers technology that allows developers to reach key audiences and to monetize in an environment where everything is free. XXX is the world leading platform for software discovery, distribution, delivery and monetization. The XXX ecosystem is comprised of four cores covering all aspects of user acquisition, conversion, monetization, integrated analytics and optimization for desktop and mobile applications."""

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I think that's quite misleading, then. It doesn't directly mention advertising at all.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Sounds like they're [leveraging synergy](http://dilbert.com/strip/1997-02-10)

Comment: I never really saw a company that advertised itself as making adware. I guess this would probably not happen really.

Comment: I can guarantee they don't refer to their own software as adware. While applications that inject ads into browsers are disgusting, they aren't illegal and there is no clear line between adware and, say, bloatware. Many AVs are considered malware-ish. And one could argue that ad-injectors are simply a "cost" of free software—while I wouldn't, the point is that the line is not defined.

Answer (score 11):

All, thanks for the discussion, and sorry for being late to the party.

In a nutshell, as long as a listing follows [our house rules](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/house-rules) and does not break the law (either by its content, or the position advertised) we leave it up to the individual applicants to decide whether they want to apply. As has been said in this thread, people tend to take offense to different things. What might upset one person may seem perfectly ok to others, and people should be able to make that decision for themselves.

Comment: I think I speak for a portion of the community when I say "Meh" as you take the more profitable stance over the just one. I beg you to reconsider if you're true to your 'making the internet a better place' mantra.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum "Making Internet better" is not "Imposing my morality". I know what is best for myself, but I don't know what is best for you. That's why you and I have to be free to make choices. If an organization is bad in my POV, then I'm free to not consume their product nor work for them.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps instead of Stack Exchange **imposing** guidelines, the system itself should support ethical scoring.

For example, Stack Overflow users could rate companies on a scale of strongly agree to strongly disagree

> Do the products and services of Company XYZ make the world a better place?

(Maybe there should also be question(s) concerning corporate funding of activism / philanthropy / political activities, but that would need a multi-dimensional rating system)

Then the average response (weighted by say the logarithm of the voter's reputation) would be calculated, displayed to job candidates, and available as a search filter.

Comment: Just thinking out loud - this is something that potentially can be easily gamed, and can also discourage a lot of companies from advertising (I know a few people who would down-vote Microsoft happily for business decisions they've made 20 years ago). Something like this needs to be very well thought out to be practical - just scoring based on rep doesn't sound too useful - maybe leaving comments (anonymous?) for some users? Not really sure.

Comment: @Benjamin: Some system documenting relevant facts, whether comment threads, wiki, or otherwise, would definitely help inform voters.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Also... weighting by a function of rep should help reduce gaming, since it makes it more difficult for sockpuppets to control the score.  And if 'softies get the cold shoulder from a significant fraction of the tech community, that probably is sufficient justification for not letting Microsoft have a perfect score.

Comment: There is a possible interpretation of the key question that goes like this: "YES we at [insert any company name] make the world a better place, because we produce income for our shareholders/personnel/CEOs". A motto warmly embraced by a lot of companies where "go green" is read as being about $$$.

Answer (score -5):

I don't even see how this is a debate. Why would SO want their business? It's not a democracy, it's a business. It fails the very basics of business ethics which Google summarized with, "Don't be evil."

Comment: SE would want their business if there are programmers out there who would want to find this job offering, and if this company is looking to fill a position.  The number of people that *wouldn't* want the job isn't relevant, the number that *would* is.  So SE would only not want their business if there are no programmers using careers that would be interested in that position.

Comment: @Servy Your statement touches some of the logical reasonings, but not any ethical ones.

Comment: Your answer states that there's no reason SO would want to allow these customers.  I gave same.  That you personally consider it unethical isn't (necessarily) a reason SE wouldn't want their business.  You would need to show that doing what you consider ethical to always be in the best interests of the business for that to be true.  (You'll find that in fact there are lots of highly successful, yet unethical, business practices, so you won't be able to successfully demonstrate that.)

Answer (score -18):

> I was wondering if it's Stack Overflow's place to impose any ethical guidelines on which companies are advertised in Careers.

No.

Comment: To thicken it a bit: Not a resolute, 100% never swearsies no. Extreme violations are an exception.

Comment: (cough - apologies for any perceived sillyness. Nevertheless...) Is that your personal opinion ("no, IMHO SO should not") or are you actually denying it already is part and parcel of SO's in-take procedure to screen advertisers?

Comment: It is my personal opinion, I'm not aware if SO places any restrictions (but assume there's some screening process)

Comment: A score of 47 for "probably not" and a -12 for "no".  :)  I guess you picked the wrong question for a one-word answer that basically agrees with the most popular one.  :)

Comment: @msouth On very serious questions, serious and thought-out answers are _very_ preferred.