# How do I alert Stack Overflow about job postings that do not have the developer first mindset?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

There are two notorious temp agencies in the Philadelphia area who fish or harvest labor, but never actually have any actual tech jobs to offer. They are just harvesting your information. Not even sure how they make their money doing that. At any rate, some greenhorn developer must have thrown "Stack Overflow" out there in the "interview" process and now these two Philadelphia temp agencies are all over the job board with what I am 99% certain are fake jobs.

This is their pattern, they fish for all the sources that you use to look for jobs and then they advertise there. They also fish for all the job interviews you have been to, down to asking who you spoke with and then they post those companies and details as if they were contracted by that company to offer temp jobs.

Stack Overflow community means a lot to me as a no-nonsense developer and I would like to know who do I need to talk to about this?

Comment: [contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/company/contact)? (link is always at the bottom of the page)...?

Comment: `[...] put the Developer first and this is what Stack Overflow is all about.` I used to believe the same but then [learned otherwise](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332037/so-careers-should-stop-accepting-business-from-predatory-employers). I'd try to contact contact the careers team directly about it anyway.

Comment: *Not even sure how they make their money doing that.* It sounds like they're resume farming: gathering resumes so they can sell them to other recruiters.

Comment: By "job postings that do not have the developer first mindset", which is a rather vague description, do you actually mean "job postings that do not exist"?

Comment: (I wonder if your first two paragraphs are not relevant here, and they can be removed? I can't quite tell.)

Comment: @halfer, your point was well taken. I removed them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you feel a job violates our policies, [please report it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reporting-companies). Our support team receives all reports and will follow up with the customer.

Comment: Is there a "REVIEW QUEUE" for companies? Can we leave an anonymous review after an interview on the experience?

Answer (score 13):

While the answer by StackOverflow indicates that they receive reports and review them - don't expect anything to be done about it.

When [I opened an issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286675/ethical-jobs-in-careers) regarding a very unethical company whose model is basically cheating less savvy computer users - I never got an official response.

The closest I got was [Tim](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286745/1348195) basically saying "Who are we to judge? How can you tell the job posting at the malware company isn't for hugging kittens?"

I was told Stack Overflow is not in the business of censoring businesses based on ethics. I'm not saying this because I think what you're asking for is wrong - I agree with it. I'm just helping set expectations so you're not disappointed. My [case was not an isolated incident](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332037/so-careers-should-stop-accepting-business-from-predatory-employers).

In fact I agree with you and in fact that case was motivation for not trusting Stack Overflow's service when I changed jobs last year although I spend a lot of time on SO writing content and trying to help out when I can and I generally like the people.

You can see this clearly in this case where instead of owning up to the promise of talent/jobs and removing the said posting (or starting a public investigation) they have subverted the criticism to a private side-channel far from the eyes of meta.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, but there seems to be a significant difference: the case you describe involves a real job at which you get paid real money for writing real software, while the case Daniel is describing in the question involves a job which is entirely fake. So I don't think it's reasonable to conclude that because SO didn't take action against the job you complained about, they necessarily also won't take action against in this case.

Comment: @DavidZ how can you know those jobs are fake? How do you know what they're offering isn't a job hugging kittens? How can you be _sure_?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, I appreciate you sharing your experience. Since relocating to the Austin area, I am noticing these "shell" companies being posted on Stack Overflow. I call them shell because a plethora of them just appeared and when you click on apply, they all take you to LinkedIn to apply. What is that all about? And some of them say, posting no longer exist. Its almost as if their intent was just to get you over to LinkedIn. Can I report this?