# Is this job posting within SO policy?

Tags: discussion, flags, stack-overflow-jobs, obscenity

Advertised on a Q&A.  The company name itself seems kind of a gray area.

(For context, according to Wikipedia, this company is

> ...an adult website providing live webcam performances by individual webcam models and couples, typically featuring nudity and sexual activity ranging from....

I'll stop there.)

The [help center for jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reporting-companies) states:

> If you notice any suspicious, inappropriate, or spammy content, please report it. Our team will review the report and take any appropriate action.

Should I have flagged the listing as inappropriate?  Or just dismiss and move on with life?

[image: A company named "Chaturbate" has a remote position for a Senior Backend Engineer. The company logo is an orange, stylized "C".]

Comment: Flag it against *what* policy? https://stackoverflow.com/help/jobs suggests recruiter spam and fake job listings aren't OK, but this doesn't appear to be either.

Comment: @jonrsharpe edited to clarify -- is this in the "inappropriate" category

Comment: I feel like this has been asked before, i just can't find the dup

Comment: There was a discussion about jobs [from a adware company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286675/ethical-jobs-in-careers/286730#286730), but it didn't receive an official answer.

Comment: Everyone on SO must really like their porn.  Also, they seem to pay a lot; it's hard to imagine their work being particularly novel, other than... y'know, the subject matter.

Comment: @RobertHarvey the pay seemed suspicious to me, but I guess it's not exactly a FANG in terms of building a resume.

Comment: @RobertHarvey:  I'd imagine that it's a bit like the finance industry.  Copious amounts of money could be shoveled in front of you, but one mistake and your career is likely toast.

Comment: Facebook, Amazon, Netflix and Google; for those of you who were wondering what the acronym meant and didn't have time to Google it.  You're welcome.

Comment: Personally, I think I'm more offended by Salesforce.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The company in question is not breaking any of our policies. If you're not interested in seeing jobs from this company, you can dismiss them from the ad, job listings, or company page.

Answer (score 16):

...So are you saying that porn companies can't also recruit engineers?

Put another way, the issue isn't with the advertisement or the posting itself, it's with the *company* doing the advertising.

It's assumed that we're all adults when applying for jobs (e.g. majority age of 18+), and I don't see any other rationale to restrict someone from wanting to apply at a job that deals in the adult entertainment industry.

If you had a specific issue with the advert in that the offer seemed dodgy, or the posting was *otherwise* inappropriate, then sure, flag it.  But I don't believe it's appropriate to flag it *just* because it's from an adult entertainment company.

Comment: So the company could be named anything, and we'd still be cool with it?  And if you think that Q&A is 18+, you haven't seen as many homework questions as I have.

Comment: That's not what this is about.  Your complaint isn't about the company's name.  It's about the industry in which the company is in.

Comment: No, if it was called "SLZY Enterprises LLC" or something I wouldn't have noticed/cared

Comment: ...which, to be blunt, is par for the course for adult entertainment companies.

Comment: `the issue isn't with the advertisement or the posting itself, it's with the company doing the advertising.` -- Is there a material difference?

Comment: @RobertHarvey:  Yes. If the company posting was something illegal or seemed to follow the pattern of recruiter exploitation, that would fly against Stack Overflow's ToS.  All I see is that it's just an adult entertainment company looking for devs which isn't against the ToS in its current incarnation.